# Generating and sending huge amount of text - how to optimize it?

Tags: javascript, php, optimization, client-server

This might be one of weirdest questions out there... sorry.

I'm trying to create a text-based web game with fight system. Let's imagine that the output of such battle looks like this:

```
ROUND 1:
AAA hit BBB for X amount of damage.
BBB hit AAA for Y amount of damage.
ROUND 2:
AAA missed BBB.
BBB hit AAA for Z amount of damage.
```

And it does go on like this for couple dozen, let's say up to 1000 lines. It's simplified example, but You got the idea. It obviously come with a lot of HTML code as well - I'll skip it to clarify the output.

Now, In order to generate this battle-report I'm generating it is such way (simplified as well, please see this as a pseudo-code just to show the idea, rather than real code):

```
$char1 = 'AAA';
$char2 = 'BBB';
$char1_hp = $char2_hp = 1000;
$msg = '';
$fight_continue = true;
$round = 1;
while ($fight_continue)
{
    $msg .= 'ROUND '.$round;
    if (mt_rand(0, 100) <= 50)
    {
        $dmg = mt_rand(1, 10);
        $char2_hp -= $dmg;
        $msg .= $char1.' hit '.$char2.' for '.$dmg.' amount of damage.';
    }
    else
        $msg .= $char1.' missed '.$char2.'.';
    
    if (mt_rand(0, 100) <= 50)
    {
        $dmg = mt_rand(1, 10);
        $char1_hp -= $dmg;
        $msg .= $char2.' hit '.$char1.' for '.$dmg.' amount of damage.';
    }
    else
        $msg .= $char2.' missed '.$char1.'.';
    
    if ($char1_hp<=0 || $char2_hp<=0)
        $fight_continue = false;
    else
        $round++;
}
```

Now there are some optimization problems. First, I'm not sure if creating such big `$msg` string is good on server side. Second, the amount of text might create a transfer problem - I'd like to save it.

I came up with a solution to "code" the report and force JS on client-side to decode it. It would look like this:

```
$char1 = 'AAA';
$char2 = 'BBB';
$char1_hp = $char2_hp = 1000;
$msg = '';
$fight_continue = true;
$round = 1;

$msg[0][1] = $char1;//input data to decode names
$msg[0][2] = $char2;//input data to decode names
while ($fight_continue)
{
    if (mt_rand(0, 100) <= 50)
    {
        $dmg = mt_rand(1, 10);
        $char2_hp -= $dmg;
        $msg[$round][1] = array(1, 1, 2, $dmg);//1, 1, 2 decodes for char1, hit, char2
    }
    else
        $msg[$round][1] = array(1, 0, 2, 0);//1, 0, 2 decodes for char1, missed, char2
    
    (...)
}
```

The battle report that client-browser will get would look like this:

```
(0 => (1=>'AAA', 2=>'BBB')), //initialization data
(1 => (0=>(1, 1, 2, 5), 1=>(2, 0, 1, 0))) //whole data for round 1
(2 => etc...) //whole data for round 2
```

Now I can printf the array and code the "visualization" part in JS (I won't present any code of how to do it since it doesn't matter for the question), just by decoding the numbers. The main downside is, that writing the "battle" code will be extreamly unintuitive - very easy to make mistakes and visualize it wrong. And the fact, that I'll need to change both battle in PHP and in JS script if I'd like to change anything.

And here comes part for the real questions:

1. How good or wrong is this idea? Perhaps gluing huge string with `$msg .= 'XXXXXXXX';` is fine, or even better than creating a huge array for server-side PHP?
2. How could it be done differently?
3. Perhaps there is a way to create "natural" text like in the first example, and than zip the text, send it to client browser, and unzip it with JS on client-side?

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps I asked i too extensively while I simply wanted to ask "how to pack text"? Anyway - thanks for the tip!

Comment: 1500 repetitions of "AAA hit BBB for X ammount of damage." is just over 50kB, uncompressed (and your webserver should compress automatically if the client supports it). That's *nothing*. Don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: This is just an example, normally the text itself will be like 2x-3x longer, and with HTML it will easily be about 500kB and more for each user, few hundrets times/day. It does concern me and I'd like to react early.

Comment: @Run_Script Code Review requires actual code from a project, the code hasn't been written yet so this is definitely off-topic there.

Comment: @Run_Script It's getting closed on Code Review. Please, only refer good-quality questions to sites you're sure where they'll be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Best practices dictate that your second method should be the better way of sending server-rendered information into and out from the front end. An AJAX interface would be the right way to make this happen.

If you want to still be able to use a "Higher Level" Interface on the backend I would recommend building your framework into something object oriented. Have an object for `person`, with functions that then read in the objects and their hit information. For this to scale effectively as a project it would be good to design it such that `damage` comes as a property from an `attack`. Then to send your information you can simply go `$personA->hits($personB, $attack);` Where `function hits(Person $p, Attack $a){}` contains takes input of person and attack and returns a string of the hit information.

In your example this would look like:

```
class Attack {
    public int $damage;
    public function getDamage(): int
    {
        return $this->damage;
    }
}

class Person {
    public string $name;
    function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    function hits(Person $p, Attack $a){
       $p->hp -= $attack->getDamage();
       //...other battle logic here
       return $this->getName . ' hit ' . $p->getName() . ' for ' $a->getDamage();
   }
}
```

Then your attack workflow would just be hitting an AJAX endpoint which processes the backend and returns what you want. This way, when you need to send the hit information to the front-end, you could just read back the string or send a `json_encoded` array of the player state and have the front-end render it, making the concerns more-neatly separated. Hope this gets you on the right path!

Comment: I'm still working on the topic. I've just learned about ob_start() - perhaps that would be the way to go, instead of complicating script and decoding it on frontend via manual js script?

Comment: It wouldn't neccessarily complicate the script on the front end. The functions I have shown here would return the data you need from purely a server-side thing. `ob_start` would simply be a way to show a buffered input, but wouldn't give you the `i/o` that you might need. The separation of concerns in a JS/PHP stack is the right way forward.